# Selecionar registro em paginação com angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paginação

Boa tarde!
Eu tenho uma tabela com paginação(uso o dir-paginate). Quando eu clico em um registro, eu invoco o ng-class e o registro muda de cor. Se eu clicar em outro registro, automaticamente o anterior que estava marcado, se desmarca, e o novo registro que recebeu o clique atual fica marcado. O problema é quando eu clico na paginação. Se o 1º registro da 1ª paginação estiver marcado e eu clicar na paginação, o 1º registro da 2ª paginação permanece marcado e assim sucessivamente. Eu queria q após clicar na paginação, o 1º registro da 1ª paginação permanecesse marcado e o 1º registro da 2ª paginação não fosse marcado. Fosse apenas quando eu clicar no mesmo.
Digamos, cliquei em Joaquim na 1º pagina.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu for p/pagina 2 Alberto virá automaticamente marcado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```js
angular.module("tabela", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
   angular.module("tabela").controller("tabelactrl", function($scope){
   
   $scope.dados = [
   {id: 1, nome: 'José'},
   {id: 2, nome: 'Maria'},
   {id: 3, nome: 'Joaquim'},
   {id: 4, nome: 'Manuel'},
   {id: 5, nome: 'Joana'},
   {id: 6, nome: 'Serafim'},
   {id: 7, nome: 'Rafaela'},
   {id: 8, nome: 'Alberto'},
   {id: 9, nome: 'Frederico'},
   {id: 10, nome: 'Juan'},
   ];
   
   $scope.itemClicked = function($index){
    $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
   };
   
   });
```

```css
 .container{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 10%;
 }
 
  .alterRow{
        background-color: #00BFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tabela">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
   
</script>
<style>


 
</style>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="tabelactrl">
   <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <td>ID</td>
       <td>Nome</td>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-click="itemClicked($index)"  ng-class="{ 'alterRow': $index === selectedIndex }" dir-paginate=" dados in dados | itemsPerPage : 5">
       <td>{{dados.id}}</td>
       <td>{{dados.nome}}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, cara... Nao utilize index nesta situação, pois o index 1 da pagina 1 é o mesmo da página 2, correto?!

Neste caso utilizei um identificador único (ID) pra funcionar, basta trocar

```html
<tr ng-click="itemClicked($index)" ng-class="{ 'alterRow': $index === selectedIndex }" dir-paginate=" dados in dados | itemsPerPage : 5">
```

por

```html
<tr ng-click="itemClicked(dados.id)" ng-class="{'alterRow': selectedIndex == dados.id}" dir-paginate="dados in dados | itemsPerPage : 5">
```